# How to update multiple groups to contact on android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I just success to insert multiple group to a contact, but failed to **update multiple group on a contact**. my code just update only 1 group, not all the list of groupsId (see below)

```
    private fun updateGroupOnContact(
        operations: ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>,
        where: String,
        args: Array<String>,
        groupsId: Array<String>
    ) {
        val values = ContentValues()

        groupsId.forEach {
            val newVal = ContentValues()
            newVal.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, it)
            values.putAll(newVal)
        }

        operations.add(
            ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(where, args)
                .withValues(values)
                .build()
        )
    }
```

I have tried this code to :

```
groupsId.forEach {

        operations.add(
            ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(where, args)
            .withValue(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, it
            )
                .build()
        )
    }
```

the code that i success **create new contact** with multiple group.

```
contentProvideOperation.add(
        ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
            .withValue(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID,
                groupID
            )
            .withValue(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            )
            .build()
    )
```

Any helps is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i got wrong id contact for insert it, I should use raw contact Id with this function.

```
private fun getRawContactId(contactId: String): String? {
        val projection = arrayOf(RawContacts._ID)
        val selection = RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?"
        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(contactId)
        val c: Cursor = contentResolver?.query(
            RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
            projection,
            selection,
            selectionArgs,
            null
        )
            ?: return null
        var rawContactId = -1
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            rawContactId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(RawContacts._ID))
        }
        c.close()
        return rawContactId.toString()
    }
```

then insert it (for adding the contact's groups), not using update.
because update is only set the group only 1 group.

```kotlin
private fun insertGroupOnContact(
            operations: ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>,
            contactId: String,
            groupId: String
        ) {
            ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI).apply {
                withValue(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, getRawContactId(contactId))
                withValue(GroupMembership.MIMETYPE, GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                withValue(GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, groupId)
                operations.add(build())
            }
        }
```

If you want to clear the previous contact's group and insert more than one. It's should update it first (1 group) to remove previous, then insert the other groups.

```
private fun updateGroupOnContact(
    operations: ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>,
    where: String,
    args: Array<String>,
    groupId: String
) {
    operations.add(
        ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(Data.CONTENT_URI)
            .withSelection(where, args)
            .withValue(GroupMembership.MIMETYPE, GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
            .withValue(GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, groupId)
            .build()
    )
}
```